# strange thing after submit a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Since two days I working on "simple" form using technology mentioned above in the title.

**The problem is:**

> After entering some string into all inputs, then I will getting nothing.
>   But, if I will enter string into one, maybe two inputs, then it will show me this string in console log.

What am I doing wrong? I checked everything and I think, that there should't been a mistake. Below I pasted my code.

At first, this is a HTML code:

```
 <form id="editUserForm">
    <input type="text" id="userName">
    <input type="text"id="userSurname">
    <input type="text" id="userEmail">
    <button type="submit" name="editUser">Send</button>
 </form>
```

Second part is a jQuery code:

```
$('#editUserForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    firstname = $('#userName').val();
    surname = $('#userSurname').val();
    email = $('#userEmail').val();

    console.log(firstname+' '+surname+' '+email);

})
```

The path is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The exact same code for me worked, maybe you are using an outdated version of jquery or javascript, I could figure out what the problem is if you show your whole html-code. And you can check out the working version here:

https://jsfiddle.net/2kcb4hvd/1/

I would also recomend declaring your variables next time like this:

```
var firstname = $('#userName').val();
var surname = $('#userSurname').val();
var email = $('#userEmail').val();
```

Comment: So, what about me? What's wrong with it? As I had written, after complement all of them inputs, it return into my console log nothing. But when I complement one, maybe two of them, then It displaying me that variable. At the moment I have using a 3.3.1 version Jquery

Comment: Maybe if you show more code I can help you out, and verify that it isn't a browser problem by checking out the jsfiddle link.

Comment: As I said before: the code is working for me, it's working in the jsfiddle link I sent you. You must show more code in order for me to help you, I can't troubleshoot if I don't see troubles.

Comment: Before I send to you my code, could you tell me, If there isn't any mistakes, the problem may be in the ajax/php code? My code is working just like that: after clicking one button, it shows me information about a person inside a input form. I would like to edit this person while changing text inside a input. I didn't write, but currently it doesn't show me any errors in the network tab, or console log

Comment: I don't understand you? What I understood from your question: you want to write firstname + " " + surname + " " + email in the console. In order to do this html, javascript and jquery will suffice. When I use the javascript and html you send it prints the exactly want you wanted on the console, so I need to see more of your html & javascript to figure out what is causing it to not work on your part.

Comment: Forget my stupid question. So... What part of code should I put here?

Answer (score 1):

Just like @TAS pointed, your code is working like it's supposed to.

**Run the code snippit to see**

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  
  <form id="editUserForm">
      <input type="text" id="userName">
      <input type="text" id="userSurname">
      <input type="text" id="userEmail">
      <button type="submit" name="editUser">Send</button>
   </form>
     
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
   
   $('#editUserForm').on('submit', function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();
       var firstname = $('#userName').val();
       var surname = $('#userSurname').val();
       var email = $('#userEmail').val();

       console.log(firstname+' '+surname+' '+email);
   });
   
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```